# java.lang.IllegalStateException while opening an dialog fragment in onloadfinished

Tags: android

In the below onloadfinished method I am trying to open an dialog fragment when result is null. However it gives me error, while opening alert dialog works fine with it.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't perform this action inside of onLoadFinished
```

What this error states here:

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Map<String, Integer>> arg0,
        Map<String, Integer> result) {
    if (result == null) {
        /*netEMessage();
         * At this place i was calling alert dialog before but Now calling Dialog in onload finished gives me error*/
        return;
    }
}



private void netEMessage() {

    NetowrkErrorDialog mErrorDialog = NetowrkErrorDialog.newInstance();
    mErrorDialog.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_NoActionBar_Fullscreen);
    mErrorDialog.setCancelable(false);
    mErrorDialog.show(mOrderActivity.getSupportFragmentManager(), "networkerror");
}
```

Complete logcat error

```
    0java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action inside of onLoadFinished
1at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1331)
2at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1338)
3at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:595)
4at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:574)
5at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:127)
6at com.fss.pos.presentation.MenuFragment.netEMessage(MenuFragment.java:178)
7at com.fss.pos.presentation.MenuFragment.onLoadFinished(MenuFragment.java:144)
8at com.fss.pos.presentation.MenuFragment.onLoadFinished(MenuFragment.java:1)
9at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.callOnLoadFinished(LoaderManager.java:427)
10at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.onLoadComplete(LoaderManager.java:395)
11at android.support.v4.content.Loader.deliverResult(Loader.java:103)
12at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.dispatchOnLoadComplete(AsyncTaskLoader.java:221)
13at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.onPostExecute(AsyncTaskLoader.java:61)
14at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask.finish(ModernAsyncTask.java:461)
15at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask.access$500(ModernAsyncTask.java:47)
16at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(ModernAsyncTask.java:474)
17at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
18at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
19at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
20at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
21at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
22at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
23at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
24at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You have a syntax error.  Missing `}` for your `onLoadFinished()`.

Comment: Show the full error log and the code version which creates the error

Comment: @Michael Butscher How to save the full log error in eclipse

Comment: @SureshBora We don't want dozens/hundreds of lines.  We want the relevant line(s) from the log.  Copy the LogCat view that you get while debugging.

Comment: The documentation for `onLoadFinished()` states: "Note that normally an application is not allowed to commit fragment transactions while in this call, since it can happen after an activity's state is saved"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you can't change, show or do something that has to do with your view or visual components. If you want to do something like that, you need user the next code:

```
An_Activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Here call your method 
        netEMessage();
    }
});
```

An_Activity is any activity (in this case the activity where you call your thread or something like that.

In your specific case put the code inside the if:

```
if (result == null) {
    /*netEMessage();
     * At this place i was calling alert dialog before but Now calling Dialog in onload finished     gives me error*/

    (Put the Code here)

    return;
}
```

Comment: But the code in the "onLoadFinished" always runs on the UI thread, in the current activity...

Answer (score 6):

Here is some background to help anyone who encounters this exception.

The exception is thrown because the framework doesn't allow to commit a fragment transaction in the same call stack as onLoadFinished().
This behavior provides a protection against state lose, because loaders are normally based on background threads (AsyncTaskLoader) which can finish their work and notify back anytime.

There could be two potential issues:
1. The framework already saved the state (for example because of orientation change) of the fragments in the fragment manager when the call to onLoadFinished() is performed.
Committing a transaction in this context will result in state lose because this late transaction is not included in the saved state.
2.  The framework has not finished restoring from a previous saved state.
Here, the transaction comes too early before the state has been restored.

There are two problems with Maria's answer above:
1. calling runOnUiThread() doesn't help because onLoadFinished() is called on the UI thread which means the call to runOnUiThread() will be called in the same call stack which will raise the exception.
The documentation says: "If the current thread is the UI thread, then the action is executed immediately." 
2. Even if the call (here DialogFragment.show()) hadn't been done in the same call stack) for example by:

```
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Map<String, Integer>> arg0,
                            Map<String, Integer> result) {
    if (result == null) {

        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                netEMessage();
            }
        });
    } 
}
```

the risks above would still exist.

The best solution to this issue is to move the fragment transaction to a different place in the flow while ensuring issues 1. and 2. above cannot happen. 
For example, performing the transaction from Activity.onPostResume().

Good luck!